# How to set the number of steps (now it's 5 points for me), when audio volume is modified by Apple keyboard (fn F10, F11, F12)

Tags: sound, keyboard, shortcut-keys, apple

When I use the Apple keyboard to increment the audio volume, the steps aren't gradual and fluid but the audio volume, in a 0 to 100 scale, it's incremented by 5 points at any key pressure and vice-versa.

How to change these steps? (Xubuntu 14.04)

tnx

Comment: An increment of 5 in the range of 0 - 100 seems to be quite gradual. Do you want smaller increment? For example ...?

Comment: I don't know why, but in my case these steps are too big.. the volume is too loud from a step to another.. I need to test other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XUBUNTU xfce4-volumed patched for pulse audio server

https://launchpad.net/xfce4-volumed-pulse

Default behaviour expected 5 steps; with the following command drops to 1:

```
xfconf-query -c xfce4-mixer -n -p /volume-step-size -s 1 -t uint
```

*Thanks to IRC **#xfce-dev** (ali1234)*